# Regex to match space separated words like CSS classes

Tags: regex

what is the correct regex to match just "name". Here in the example just the first word, it can be somewhere between, too. The input can just "name" as well.

```
name dasasd nameasdas name-dasds-das
```

Comment: The question is not completely clear to me. Do you only want to match the first word, regardless of its value?

Comment: nope it will match "-" as space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like:

```
(^|\s)name(\s|$)
```

- starting at the beginning of the string (^) or after whitespace
- ending at the end of the string ($) or before whitespace

See e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the first ritd:

```
^\w+
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to Bohemain's answer, You could simply use

`/name/`   will just match first, by default regex matches just the first occurence in the array

`/name/g`  will match all the three(multiple occurrences of name in string)